# Sqlite comparison of the same operand types behaves differently

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Based on Sqlite docs: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison, especially this statement:

> If one operand has INTEGER, REAL or NUMERIC affinity and the other operand has TEXT or BLOB or no affinity then NUMERIC affinity is applied to other operand.

I would expect the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `amount` DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT NULL
);

insert into `invoice` (`amount`) values (4.0);
insert into `invoice` (`amount`) values (15.0);
insert into `invoice` (`amount`) values (4.0);

select *,
    typeof(amount), amount = '4',
    typeof(sum(amount)), sum(amount) = '4', sum(amount) = '4.0', sum(amount) = 4
from invoice
group by id;
```

to return the same result for `sum(amount) = '4'` as for `amount = '4'` for each row as both operand types have the same type in each comparison (verified using `typeof()`, for non-`SUM()` the comparison is working as expected).

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/59238/2

Comment: It seems that SUM() result have no affinity rather than a column value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Type affinity* should not be confused with *Data Type* (which Sqlite calls *Storage Class*).

Every single value in Sqlite has a Storage Class, which is always either NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT or BLOB.

4 is a value of the INTEGER storage class.
'xyz' is a value of the TEXT storage class.

Note that `typeof()` returns the *Storage class* of a value, not the *type affinity* of the column.

Since in Sqlite columns are not required to have a specific storage class, and you can store both 4 or 'xyz' in the same column, Sqlite introduced the concept of Type Affinity, which is an indication of which kind of values SHOULD be stored in that column, if possible.
So if you declare a column

```
amount DOUBLE PRECISION
```

you are actually saying that amount *should* contain REAL values (has a REAL *type affinity*), but the actual values can be of any type.

Sqlite tries to satisfy this affinity when you insert a value of `'4'` into `amount`: it converts it to a REAL value before storing it. But if you insert a value of `'xyz'`, it cannot convert it to a REAL and it will store the value as a TEXT.

When you use the column `amount` in a query, Sqlite presumes that the values stored in the column *should* be REAL values. So when it does the comparison `amount = '4'` , it will apply rules for type affinity: `'4'` will be converted to a REAL and compared to what is stored in the column.

Since ***type affinity* is dictated by the column definition at create time**, and not by the single values contained, this implies that:

**A**. Type affinity of `amount` will always be REAL, even when the value contained in a row is `'xyz'`.

**B**. Anything that is not a column has never been declared with a type affinity, so any expression that is not a simple reference to a column of a real table, or is not explictly CASTed, doesn't have a type affinity.

This means that `4` and `'4'` have no type affinity (even if they are constants of the INTEGER and TEXT storage class, respectively).
Also `amount+10`, `sum(amount)` or `min(amount)` are all expressions that don't have a type affinity (you didn't declare to Sqlite which type those expressions *should* be), but, when evaluated for every single row, they will evaluate to a value in a specific storage class.

This is why:

- `4 = '4'` is FALSE, because neither has a type affinity and sqlite compares an integer with a string
- `amount = '4'` is TRUE when a `4` is stored in the row, because since amount has a type affinity of REAL, sqlite expects all the values contained should be real and converts `'4'` to `4` before the comparison.
- `sum(amount) = '4'` is FALSE even when the sum is actually `4`, because `sum(amount)` is not a simple reference to a column, it's an expression and thus it has no type affinity. `4` is then compared to `'4'` and the result is false as in the first example.
- **but** `CAST(sum(amount) AS REAL) = '4'` **is TRUE** when the sum is actually `4`, because the CAST assigns a REAL type affinity to the left hand expression, so sqlite knows it has to convert the right hand `'4'` to `4` before comparison.

Also, if I understand correctly, while storage classes are checked and evaluated at runtime (because different rows can have different `amount` values of different storage classes), I think type affinity is evaluated at prepare time, so any necessary conversion is actually established, for every row, before checking the values in the rows.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is, sadly, the current & documented behavour (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_of_expressions). You are also right about the "affinity" beiing computed once and "storage class" to be computed per each value. As this leads to very illogical and inconsistent results, I would welcome any contribution in fixing this by propagating the affinity thru the expressions. `a + b = 4` should simply be true when for ex. `a = 3 and b = 1` is true.

Comment: @mvorisek Unfortunately, changing this behaviour and propagating the affinity thru expressions would break backward compatibility, which is a thing that Sqlite has never done since version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

I think you've spotted a slight inconsistency in the behaviour of SQLite! All of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tMRW418b).

First we have:

```
SELECT 4 = '4' AS "INT_to_TEXT";  -- No coercion because it's not a field!
```

Result:

```
INT_to_TEXT
          0  <<--- FALSE!
```

Then we do this:

```
SELECT 4 = CAST('4' AS INTEGER) AS "Casted";  -- <<-- Explicit CAST required
```

Result:

```
Casted
     1  <<--- TRUE!
```

So, now we try the table:

```
SELECT
  amount = 4  AS "Int",
  amount = '4' AS "Coerced" -- <<-- Implicit coercion occurs here because it's a field!
FROM
  invoice;
```

Result:

```
Int Coerced
  1       1    = 4  therefore TRUE
  0       0    = 15 therefore FALSE  4 != 15 any way you do it!
  1       1    = 4  therefore TRUE
```

Finally,

```
SELECT
  SUM(amount) AS    "The sum (INT)",
  SUM(amount) = 4 AS "Expected", -- <<---- t/f/t as expected
  SUM(amount) = '4' AS "No coercion 1",    -- <<--- All FALSE
  SUM(amount) = CAST('4' AS INTEGER) AS "Casted", -- <<--- t/f/t as expected 
  SUM(amount) = '4.0' "No coercion 2"   -- <<--- All FALSE
FROM
  invoice
GROUP BY id;
```

Result:

```
The sum (INT)  Expected  No coercion 1  Casted  No coercion 2
            4         1              0       1              0
           15         0              0       0              0
            4         1              0       1              0
```

So, the cases where it's f/f/f are the ones where you try and coerce SUM(amount) to match TEXT! It seems to me that what's happening is that SQLite becomes confused when you try and implicitly coerce a string to match a SUM. I thought it might be all aggregate functions, but it's not!

Check this out:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) = 3,
  COUNT(*) = '3',   -- <<---- t/f COUNT() has the same behaviour as SUM
  MAX(amount) = 15,
  MAX(amount) = 15  -- <<---- t/t But, MAX() does not! 
FROM
  invoice;
```

Result:

```
COUNT(*) = 3  COUNT(*) = '3' MAX(amount) = 15 MAX(amount) = 15
           1              0                 1                1
```

So, for COUNT, it's t/f but for MAX, it's t/t!

As I said, I think you've discovered a discrepancy in the behaviour of SQLite, unless of course D. Richard Hipp is using some logic which I haven't quite understood - and he's a pretty smart cookie! Shall you report it or shall I?

Although, quite what **utter lunatic** would actually want to do this "in real life" is **way way** beyond my pay grade! :-)

And finally, just an FYI, you don't need backticks for SQLite - even MySQL doesn't require them any longer! +1 for an interesting post!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your post and the discovery about MAX! Yes, given `MAX(numeric type)` and even `SUM(numeric table field)` transfer the type knowledge to the result, it seems like an inconsistency in SQLite. The same for `4 = '4'`. I would really appreatiate if you will report it.

Comment: OK - will do! Even though the practical consequences are unlikely to be colossal! :-)

Comment: One/my usecase is when the one side of a compare expression is comming from bound param which can be of type string. In PHP, there is not even native float bound param type - https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php and string must be used. In https://dbfiddle.uk/sLG3w94u I found something even more surprising - `+` operator with numeric values is broken too.

Comment: Put up a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) and I'll tale a look!

Comment: The fiddle is in my last post. The behaviour is documented in: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_of_expressions . Currently, sadly, all math expressions in SQLite do not imply affinity. I tested MySQL/MariaDB, T-SQL/MSSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle and all of these DBs handle the affinity correctly. It is probably some historical SQLite behaviour and any help with fixing this is highly welcomed.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you dig into some C  textbooks and write some sort of function? SQLite isn't really my bady - I'm more of a PostgreSQL man...

Comment: @Vérace there is an error in your fiddle, you repeated two times   `MAX(amount) = 15`, instead of   `MAX(amount) = '15'`

Comment: @AndreaB. OMG - you're right. Thanks for pointing that out - I'll tell the OP so that my answer can be "demoted"!

Comment: @mvorisek - please see AndreaB.'s point above. Please revoke the correct answer tick as it is not deserved! Sorry about that!

Comment: @Vérace My answer should explain the discrepancy of the results in your fiddle.